# How to set rating value as empty?

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I want to collect rating of my book. link:
http://www.jegeachi.com/detail/1

Here initial rating value is : 5 out of 5. So if user missed to choose this field 5 will be inserted. This may be changed as 4.50 or 3.00. but it will be always 5 if user missed to choose rating field. Here is the code of rating field:

```
  <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="rating">Rating</label>
                            <?php
                            echo $this->Form->input(
                                    'rating', array(
                                'class' => 'form-control required ',
                                'type' => 'range',
                                'value' => 5,
                                'step' => 0.25,
                                'id' => 'backing5'
                                    )
                            );
                            ?>
                            <div class="rateit" data-rateit-backingfld="#backing5" data-rateit-resetable="false"  data-rateit-ispreset="true" data-rateit-min="0" data-rateit-max="5">
```

I want to change 'value' => 5, as 'value' => null, or 'value' => 0,  but these does not work. What I need to set 'value' as empty for which 'required' class will applied and give warning that a required field is not filled up. this required class is working for other class but I cann't set a value of rating so that it is treated as unfilled. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding `'allowEmpty' => true` to the validation rule?

```
public $validate = array(
    'rating' => array(
        'rule' => array('range', 0, 5),
        'message' => 'Please enter a number between 0 and 5'
        'allowEmpty' => true
    )
);
```